# Console Error with Assets when Attempting to Index Amazon S3 folder

Tags: assets

When I attempt to Index an Amazon S3 folder, I was getting no response. I get the bar, but no progress.

Everything works fine when I'm indexing a local folder.

So I tried doing it with the Console on while in Firefox and got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical @ 
{my site name}/themes/third_party/assets/scripts/assets.min.js?2.0.5:11
```

Safari gives a similar error:

```
SyntaxError: Expected token ')'
```

I'm using Assets 2.0.5 on EE 2.5.5

If you need other details to diagnose, let me know...

Edited to add:

Ran it in the Firebug console - Syntax Error appears to be related to a memory problem:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (trie

assets.js?2.0.5 (line 5618, col 6)
```

Comment: I'm having the same SyntaxError: Expected token ')' issue with EE 2.7.1 and Assets 2.1.4. I tried using the config['assets_use_uncompressed_js'] = TRUE; flag and still got the same error. Safari console says "SyntaxError: Expected token ')' on assets.js:5725". I downloaded a fresh copy of Assets from Devot-ee thinking my copy of the JS file was corrupted, but I get the same result even after replacing all Assets resources.

Comment: To be clear, this is happening when I go to update my indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I found the answer to my own problem. I was storing three years worth of Logs in my Amazon S3 folder which made an insane number of files for Assets to index, causing the memory error.

So if you turn on Logging for Amazon S3, don't keep the logs in the same bucket that you keep your... ahem... assets. Keep the logs in a separate log-only bucket that you don't hook up with Assets.

Answer (score 1):

that's really odd.

You can either try re-uploading that file (because it kind of seems that it wasn't uploaded correctly), or you can try adding this line to your ExpressionEngine config:
$config['assets_use_uncompressed_js'] = TRUE;

Cheers,
Andris

Comment: Andris - unfortunately, neither has worked for me...  reuploaded the entire folder and got the error. And then when I switched the config to use the "Uncompressed" version, I get the same error but for assets.js

Comment: Todd, can you go ahead and send us SuperAdmin and FTP details via support@pixelandtonic.com?  That is a bit odd and I suspect it'd be faster if we login to troubleshoot.  Please link to this thread when you email!

Comment: Sent. Also have more details that I've added to the main post...