# S3 Index Javascript Errors

Tags: assets, s3

Having the same issue as in this thread:

[Console Error with Assets when Attempting to Index Amazon S3 folder](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7527/console-error-with-assets-when-attempting-to-index-amazon-s3-folder/7569#7569)

When trying to update the index for an S3 source, getting the following error in the Firebug console:

```
missing ) in parenthetical
</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;"
assets.js?2.0.5 (line 5626, col 11)
```

This was working fine until recently adding additional folders within an S3 bucket. Any ideas?

---

UPDATE: 04/01/2013

This issue ended up being an NAT issue with the Amazon cloud server, which is behind a firewall. It was blocking all outgoing requests. This is what was causing the JS errors I'm assuming.

I discovered this by editing my S3 source and trying to refresh the bucket list. Eventually I got the following error message:

```
Access denied by target host
```

Comment: What version, Synergema? And have you already tried uploading a fresh copy of the folders, both assets primary folder and the themes folder? Also, do you have any local File Upload preferences? Or is this all S3?

Comment: Hi Lisa, Uploaded a fresh copy of all Assets files to the server, still getting the same JS error. We do have some local uploads, but trying to migrate all of those assets to S3. This was definitely working, so I'm a little perplexed as to what would have changed. Could it be something with the S3 source, permissions, etc? Unfortunately, the JS error doesn't give much hint, to me at least.

Comment: Also, running Assets 2.0.5

Comment: Synergema - I may need to have a look on your server; but before we do that, can you test in another browser and see if it is browser specific?  thank you!

Comment: Thanks Lisa. Ended up tracking this one down, and updated my original post. This was a firewall issue. May be something to look at for the future though, that if Assets doesn't get a valid response from S3, that some error is displayed. As always, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Synergema - I just now posted that to our list for consideration. Thanks for letting me know what you found out! Definitely something to account for in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per original question poster's comment above:

> Thanks, Lisa. Ended up tracking this one down, and updated my original post. This was a firewall issue. May be something to look at for the future though, that if Assets doesn't get a valid response from S3, that some error is displayed. As always, thanks for your help!